# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching example.com found

Tags: ssl

I'm using a rest service to fetch data. Twice in the past several months, I received the following error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching example.com found.`

I've read several posts that says it's something to do with LDAPS but LDAPS has nothing to do with the server/service I'm using. The problem seems to happen for several seconds and disappears on its own.

I don't have access to that server and the support told me that they did nothing nor changed anything from their side.

Not sure if it's related, I updated my lets encrypt certificate few days ago and the problem happened for several seconds a day and a half after I restarted my tomcat/java with the new certificate.

Any idea what to look for? Thanks

Comment: Look for `example.com` in the Subject Alternate Name extension of your new Let's Encrypt certificate.

Comment: Where/how can I do that? My guess is it won't be there. Do I need to add it every time I renew the certificate?

Comment: `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <lets encrypt certificate>` will show you the details of the cert.  You need to request all the names your certificate will be valid for when you run `certbot` (or whatever you use).  For `certbot` you use the `-d <fqdn>` option.  You can use multiple `-d` options.

Comment: I ran the openssl command and saw this: X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com (both are my domain). I guess that makes sense. The error I receive is when my tomcat is calling an API service outside of my server.

Comment: Then you must call the API service using a hostname that matches the Subject Alternate Name in that service's certificate.

Comment: Meaning the problem is on their side/certificate? They said they did nothing but maybe they didn't know something was happening behind the scenes and since it vanished after few seconds, maybe it was a temporary maintenance... go figure. Thanks!